# I am unable to add authorization in POSTMAN flows

Tags: postman, postman-flows

I am unable to add authorization in the POSTMAN Flows. I have added authorization as a global variable but am unable to get it in POSTMAN flows.

[image]

I have added authorization as a global variable but am unable to get it in POSTMAN flows. I want authorization as a variable in the POSTMAN flows.